# page not rendered from module

Tags: 7

i would show a page not themed by drupal from a specific path from my custom module.

I'm using drupal7.

Here is the example module:

file: custom_example.module

```
<?php
/*
 * Implementation of hook_menu()
 */
function custom_example_menu(){
  $items['foo/bar'] = array(
    'title' => 'Page Title',
    'description' => 'Simple custom hook_menu() implementation.',
    'page callback' => 'my_page_function',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/*
 * Returns custom content to Drupal
 */
function my_page_function(){
   return theme('my_custom_template');
}

/*
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function custom_example_theme(){
  return array(
    'my_custom_template' => array(
      'template' => 'custom-page',
    ),
  );
}
```

file:custom-page.tpl.php

```
<html>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine to show the page at mysite.com/foo/bar link but the page is themed with all drupal stuffs (header footer sidebar) that i don't want.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to do something like this in your my_page_function

```
$output = '<html>
<body>
<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>';

print $output;
die;
```

So don't return anything. It's not great and avoids everything drupal related really but it sounds like what you want to do. As using anything to do with drupal's theme functions will always be wrapped in the site of the site content

Comment: thanks, this works but i'd prefer to wait for some solution as overwrite or preprocess functions, die seems so.... deadly :D

Comment: The only other obvious thing I can think of would be you'd have another theme and you'd strip out anything you dont want from the html.tpl file of that theme. Then you'd need to do a theme suggestion for this page to tell Drupal to use that theme instead of your current one for this specific page